# How to keep track of selected component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a coding challenge and I'm having problems to navigate back and forth between my components. Here's what a very simplified version of my parent component looks like:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState({
    shoppingBasket: true,
    contactDetails: false,
    paymentOptions: false,
    checkout: false,
    summary: false
  });

  const switchState = input => {
    const { name, value } = input.target;
    setComponent({
      ...component,
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  return (
  <>
    {
      component.shoppingBasket && 
      <ShoppingBasket
        shoppingBasket={component.shoppingBasket}
        switchState={switchState}
      />
    }
    {
      component.contactDetails && 
      <ContactDetails
        contactDetails={component.contactDetails}
        switchState={switchState}
      />
    }
    {
      component.paymentOptions && 
      <PaymentOptions
        paymentOptions={component.paymentOptions}
        switchState={switchState}
      />
    }
    {
      component.checkout && 
      <Checkout
        checkout={component.checkout}
        switchState={switchState}
      />
    }
    {
      component.summary && 
      <Summary
        summary={component.summary}
        switchState={switchState}
      />
    }
  </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It's supposed to be the checkout screen of an e-commerce page and it starts with the `<ShoppingBasket />` component. When clicking "Continue", it shows the next component, when clicking "Back" it goes back to the previous one. They should appear in the order shown in the code.

My first attempt was to show the next component only when the previous one(s) evaluate true but at the end it was showing *all* of the components, so that didn't work. Note: I passed the switchState function and the respective state as prop to the child component.

I guess the smartest way is to show only the component that is currently selected but how do I do that? I assume working with IDs?

And would it be still necessary to keep track of the previous components evaluating to true, when it's only showing the selected one anyway?

---

### **SOLUTION:**

Parent component (simplified but working):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// COMPONENTS
import ShoppingBasket from './components/ShoppingBasket';
import PaymentOptions from './components/PaymentOptions';
import ContactDetails from './components/ContactDetails';
import Checkout from './components/Checkout';
import Summary from './components/Summary';

export default function App() {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState(0);
  const switchComponent = (index) => {
    setComponent(index);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {
        {
          0: <ShoppingBasket switchComponent={switchComponent} />,
          1: <ContactDetails switchComponent={switchComponent} />,
          2: <PaymentOptions switchComponent={switchComponent} />,
          3: <Checkout switchComponent={switchComponent} />,
          4: <Summary />,
        }[component]
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

Child component with index 3 (also simplified):

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Checkout({ switchComponent }) {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => switchComponent(2)}>BACK</button>
      <button onClick={() => switchComponent(4)}>CONTINUE</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

    const [component, setComponent] = useState(0);

    const switchComponent = index => {
        setComponent(index);
    };

    return (
        <>
            {
                // this act like switch case js function
                {
                    0:
                        (<ShoppingBasket
                            //shoppingBasket={component.shoppingBasket} // no need for this 
                            componentIndex={component}
                            switchState={switchComponent}
                        />),
                    1:
                        (<ContactDetails
                            // contactDetails={component.contactDetails}
                            componentIndex={component}
                            switchState={switchComponent}
                        />),
                    2:
                        (<PaymentOptions
                            // paymentOptions={component.paymentOptions}
                            componentIndex={component}
                            switchState={switchComponent}
                        />),
                    3:
                        (<Checkout
                            // checkout={component.checkout}
                            componentIndex={component}
                            switchState={switchComponent}
                        />),
                    4:
                        (<Summary
                            // summary={component.summary}
                            componentIndex={component}
                            switchState={switchComponent}
                        />)
                }[component]
            }
        </>
    );

}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi Nassim, thank you very much for your quick reply! I've updated my original post according to your answer and also added the missing props to the components. How would you design the event handler **switchState**? Right now it doesn't have any effect and I only want to set the state of the component to true that is being displayed. So every component before or after should equal false. If this approach makes sense... Appreciate the help!

Comment: in React passing functions as props down child component so you can update the parrent state is very common. so yes the way you've designed it to work is fine, but you can simplify it. see update

Comment: Thanks again, it's almost working! I can't figure out how to pass the index in the `switchComponent` method though. Inside a child component, when entering one of the numbers in the click handler it's perfectly working: `onClick={switchComponent(4)}`. But let's say I'm in component 1 and want to go to 0 by pressing "Back" and to 2 by pressing "Continue". How do I use the `componentIndex` prop im passing to the child correctly?

Comment: see the answer below, hope this answers to your question

Answer (score 0):

**ShoppingBasket.js**

```
const ShoppingBasket = props => {

  return (
    // your ShoppingBasket component .....
  )

}
```

** ContactDetails.js**

```
const ContactDetails = props => {

  return (
    // your ContactDetails component .....
  )

}
```

....... the same for other components

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

const [component, setComponent] = useState(0);

const switchComponent = index => {
    setComponent(index);
};

return (
    <>
        {
            // this act like switch case js function
            // 
            {
                0:
                    (<ShoppingBasket/>),
                1:
                    (<ContactDetails/>),
                2:
                    (<PaymentOptions/>),
                3:
                    (<Checkout/>),
                4:
                    (<Summary/>)
            }[component]
        }

  // navigation buttons .... always visible
      <NavigateButtons 
         componentIndex={component}
         switchState={switchComponent} 
      /> 
    </>
);
```

}

export default App;

----------------------------------***----------------

**Note** : make sure the buttons next and previous are just one splited component so you can use it in diffrent other components

```
const NavigateButtons = (props) => ( 
<div>
   <Button  
      disabled={componentIndex == 4} 
      onClick={()=> props.switchState(componentIndex + 1)}>next
      </Button>
   <Button 
       disabled={componentIndex == 0}
       onClick={()=> props.switchState(componentIndex - 1)}>previous
       </Button>
</div>
)
```